# Initialise call back function

Tags: jquery, select, callback

I have this piece of jQuery which is using a call back on selection.

```
 new Shopify.OptionSelectors("product-variants", {product: product, onVariantSelected: selectCallback}); // initialize multi selector for product
```

however when I try to select using jQuery it doesn't initialise the callback

```
 $("#product-variants-option-0 option[value=" + selectedVal+"]").attr("selected","selected") ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing attribute in the code doesn't suppose to fire any callbacks, there are two ways to handle it. First after setting the attribute you should fire he callback yourself or you probably might need to use trigger function instead of trying to change attribute:

```
 $( "radio-button-selector").trigger( "select");
```

or even simulate a click:

```
 $( "radio-button-selector").trigger( "click");
```